# numpy.concatenate((A, B, C)) = A when B and C are None

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following piece of code inside the following function:-

```
import numpy as np

def fun(A, B=None, C=None):
      M = np.concatenate((A, B, C))
```

Where A, B, and C are matrices with the same number of columns.

When B and C are NOT None, there is no problem. However, when at least one of them is None, we will have an error with the dimensions.

**My Question: is there an elegant way to have  `M = np.concatenate((A, B, C)) = A` when both B and C are None?**

Comment: It may be better to change the signature to `fun(A, *args)` and concatenate like `np.concatenate((A,) + args)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Variable-length Argument:

```
>>> def connect(A, *args):
...     return np.concatenate((A,) + args)
...
>>> connect(np.arange(10))
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> connect(np.arange(10), np.arange(5))
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> connect(*([np.arange(3)] * 5))
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: Thank you! 
In fact, I need to know B and C explicitly for the rest of the code, so it's more convenient to define them like in the description above. I'd appreciate it if you have any other ideas that go along with this definition.

Comment: @IyadWalweel Consider `np.concatenate([ar for ar in (A, B, C) if ar is not None])`